# How to replace + with . (fullstop) using python replace

Tags: python, replace

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
AccidentData=AccidentData.replace(regex=["'+'"], value='.')
```

But some reason this is not working.

Comment: What is `AccidentData` ?

Comment: This isn't enough code, or enough explanation of the problem. What actually happened when you tried the code? Where does the `AccidentData` value come from, and what type is it?

Answer (score 0):

If you call replace on a string, you do not need a regex:

```
"a+b+c+d".replace('+', '.')  # --> 'a.b.c.d'
```

Maybe you should try:

```
str(AccidentData).replace('+', '.')
```